# Redux-Form loading component from another file freezes the loading

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

When I try to import field from external file, the page freezes(takes forever to load). I think the problem is `component={SurveyField}` because if I code `component="input"` instead, it works.
But I really want to import form from outside.
Thanks for your help in advance!

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { reduxForm, Field } from "redux-form";
import SurveyField from "./SurveyForm";

class SurveyForm extends Component {
  renderFields = () => {
        return <Field type="text" name="title" component= 
   {SurveyField} />;
    };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit(values => 
console.log(values))}>
          <Field type="text" name="title" component={SurveyField} />
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: "surveyForm"
})(SurveyForm);
```

This is SurveyField.js
    import React from "react";

```
const SurveyField = () => {
  return <input />;
};

export default SurveyField;
```

Answer (score 0):

You import SurveyField from SurveyForm.js not SurveyField.js. It could be the problem